# Why do I get a DuplicateKeyException in Linq2Sql after I checked for the keys existence?

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a program that adds a lot of new data to a database using Linq2SQL.

In order to avoid DuplicateKeyExceptions, I check for the existence of the key, before trying to add a new value into the database.

As of now, I can't provide an isolated test-case, but I have simplified the code as much as possible.

```
// newValue is created outside of this function, with data read from a file
// The code is supposed to either add new values to the database, or update existing ones

var entryWithSamePrimaryKey = db.Values.FirstOrDefault(row => row.TimestampUtc == newValue.TimestampUtc && row.MeterID == newValue.MeterID);
if (entryWithSamePrimaryKey == null)
{
    db.Values.InsertOnSubmit(newValue);
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
else if(entryWithSamePrimaryKey.VALUE != newValue.VALUE)
{
    db.Values.DeleteOnSubmit(entryWithSamePrimaryKey);
    db.SubmitChanges();
    db.Values.InsertOnSubmit(newValue);
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Strangely enough, when I look at the exceptions in the application log, as to which items cause trouble, I am unable to find ANY of them in the database.

I suspect this happens within the update code, so that the items get removed from the database, but not added again.

I will update my code to deliver more information, and then update this post accordingly.

Comment: Turns out the best solution I could find to solve this, is to not 'SubmitChanges' for every item, but cache them in a list (to be able to compare for duplicates), and then flush them afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

If the error is generated in the update block, you can merge the object in the update case without deleting `entryWithSamePrimaryKey`, but valorizing it with the property value of `newValue` and than save the changes.

Comment: I have a testcase running, that does just that (takes about half a day for a full run). I just thought it is cleaner to just use the new entity, instead of copying the values of all properties. Also, I feel like this is a bug somewhere, and shipping around it isn't the right way to go.

Comment: ok, but I don't think it's an error of the change processor. Try to remove the object from the ObjectContext after the delete and before you insert the newValue. (i.e. db.Values.Remove(entryWithSamePrimaryKey) )

Comment: I don't have Add/Remove functions, just InsertOnSubmit and DeleteOnSubmit. I thought Add/Remove were deperecated functions by now. Will do some checking on that.